# Warbler with Bundler and Jruby seems to be broken

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems, bundler, warbler

When warbler creates the war file and I deploy it into tomcat I get a GemNotFound error.  We use a CI docker node in GitLab to create our deployed war files.  I will include that below as well, I have been hacking at it so it is a mess.  I have tried every combination of suggestions but havent found anything.  The error I am getting when the war is deployed: GemNotFound unable to load thrift libraries

Gemfile

```
# Local Gem Repository used in production
source 'http://nexus3/repository/rubygems/'

gem 'rails'

gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter'

# Use SASS for stylesheets
gem 'sassc-rails'

# Use Twitter Bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# Icon font
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyrhino'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# To use debugger
#gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
#gem 'ruby-debug-base'
#gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

gem 'responders'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'warbler', :require => false
  gem 'jruby-jars'

  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'jruby-lint', :require => false

  #jasmine tests
  gem 'jasmine'
  #gem 'guard'
  #gem 'guard-jasmine'


  #test
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'apparition', git: 'https://github.com/twalpole/apparition.git'
  gem 'capybara-screenshot'
  gem 'jruby-rack'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', :require => false
  gem 'webrat'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', :require => false
  gem 'foreman'

  #code quality
  gem 'metric_fu'

  gem 'simplecov', :require => false, :group => :test
  #gem 'pry-byebug'
  #gem 'pry-nav'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'knockoutjs-rails'
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem 'underscore-rails'
gem 'respond-js-rails'
gem 'sammyjs-rails', git: 'https://github.com/szechyjs/sammyjs-rails.git'
gem 'momentjs-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-growl-rails'
gem 'animate-rails'

gem 'browserify-rails'

gem 'rest-client'
gem 'rubyzip'

gem 'semver2'

# Attachment Uploader
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'

# XML Parser with XPATH support
gem 'nokogiri'

# Rails server is slow, use puma
gem 'puma'

gem 'tinymce-rails'

# Use thrift for services
gem 'thrift', '0.11.0'
gem 'thrift_client', '0.11.0'

gem 'html5shiv-rails'
#gem 'rake-minify' #this is used for the tinymce plugins we have - see the minification.rb initializer
```

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker.corp.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

variables:
  JRUBY_OPTS: "--debug -J-Xmx2G"
  CI_COMMON: /share/clones/ci-common/develop
  #BUNDLE_PATH: ""

before_script:
  - git submodule init
  - git submodule update
  - cd server
  - unset BUNDLE_PATH
  - unset GEM_HOME
  - unset GEM_PATH
  - export BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG=vendor/bundle
  #- export GEM_PATH=vendor/bundle
  #- gem install bundler -v 2.1.4
  #- bin/bundle config deployment true
 # - bin/bundle config path vendor/bundle
#  - bundle config disable_shared_gems true
#  - bundle binstubs
  - bin/bundle install -j$(nproc) --binstubs --deployment
  - npm install --quiet
#  - bundle check
  - bin/bundle exec gem env
  - bin/bundle config

#cache:
#  paths:
#    - server/.bundle/
#    - server/vendor/bundle/
#    - server/node_modules/
#    - server/bin/

stages:
#  - test
  - build
  - omnibus-build
  - omnibus-install

#rspec:
#  stage: test
#  tags:
#    - docker
#  except:
#    - tags
#  script:
#    - bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
#    - bin/rspec

#cucumber:
#  stage: test
#  tags:
#    - docker
#  except:
#    - tags
#  script:
#    - bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
#    - bin/cucumber

#changelog-check:
#  except:
#    - develop
#    - /^release.*$/
#  stage: test
#  allow_failure: true
 # tags:
 #   - docker
 # script:
 #   - $CI_COMMON/changelog-check $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME

war:
  stage: build
  only:
    - develop
    - /^release.*$/
    - production-fix
  tags:
    - docker
  except:
    - tags
  script:
#    - rake war:debug
    - bin/rake build:war
    - mkdir -p /share/artifacts/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
    - rm -f /share/artifacts/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.tar.gz
    - tar -zcf /share/artifacts/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME.tar.gz ROOT.war

...
```

Output of the command `bin/bundle config` and the output of `bin/bundle exec gem env` from within my yml file:

```
bin/bundle exec gem env
 RubyGems Environment:
   - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.6
   - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.7 (2020-03-25 patchlevel 0) [java]
   - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0
   - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/jruby/2.5.0
   - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/jruby/bin/jruby
   - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/git
   - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/bin
   - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
   - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/jruby/etc
   - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - universal-java-1.8
   - GEM PATHS:
      - /builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0
   - GEM CONFIGURATION:
      - :update_sources => true
      - :verbose => true
      - :backtrace => false
      - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - "install" => "--no-document"
      - "update" => "--no-document"
   - REMOTE SOURCES:
      - https://rubygems.org/
   - SHELL PATH:
      - /builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/bin
      - /usr/local/bundle/bin
      - /opt/jruby/bin
      - /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin
      - /usr/local/sbin
      - /usr/local/bin
      - /usr/sbin
      - /usr/bin
      - /sbin
      - /bin
 $ bin/bundle config
 Settings are listed in order of priority. The top value will be used.
 deployment
 Set for your local app (/builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/config): true
 path
 Set for your local app (/builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"
 bin
 Set for your local app (/builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/config): "bin"
 Set via BUNDLE_BIN: "/usr/local/bundle/bin"
 jobs
 Set for your local app (/builds/mrts/WebRET/server/vendor/bundle/config): 48
 app_config
 Set via BUNDLE_APP_CONFIG: "vendor/bundle"
 silence_root_warning
 Set via BUNDLE_SILENCE_ROOT_WARNING: true
 gemfile
 Set via BUNDLE_GEMFILE: "/builds/mrts/WebRET/server/Gemfile"
```

Dockerfile used to create docker container:

```
FROM jruby:9.2.11.1-jdk

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install chrome
ENV CHROME_VERSION "google-chrome-stable"
RUN sed -i -- 's&deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main&#deb http://deb.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main&g' /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update && apt-get install wget -y
ENV CHROME_VERSION "google-chrome-stable"
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
  && apt-get update && apt-get -qqy install ${CHROME_VERSION:-google-chrome-stable}

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key"; \
  done

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
#ENV NODE_VERSION 4.2.1
ENV NODE_VERSION 10.15.2

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --verify SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz\$" SHASUMS256.txt.asc | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xzf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.gz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc

ADD id_rsa /root/.ssh/
RUN /bin/echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\tUserKnownHostsFile /dev/null\n\n" > /root/.ssh/config

RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh && chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I noticed that you're using a custom gem server. Any chance that the library `thrift` is not there? Try loading the gem from it's git repository and check whether that works.

Comment: Good thought and I had thought that myself.  We used thrift 0.9.3 previously so I reverted back to that since I knew it was in the custom gem server and then the error changed from not being able to load thrift 0.11.0 to not being able to load thrift 0.9.3.

Comment: I see. I'm not a specialist in ruby gem servers, there might be some sort of misconfiguration, but is there any reason why you need ALL the gems to be loaded from your private server? Using a git repo like you use with em 'sammyjs-rails' seems to be a workaround ^^;

Comment: We don't always have the internet at our disposal for various reasons, so we need to host our own server.  As a test I have pointed it to `'source http://rubygems.org` with the same result.

Comment: If you are asking about bundler and jruby, what is gitlab ci config for?

Comment: Because the output of the `bin/bundle config` and `bin/bundle exec gem env` are coming from the docker container.  Also, I wanted to provide as much information about my issue as possible to inform the community of my issue.